# Rollout deployment based on selector in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

In the namespace, I have multiple applications deployed. I would like to rollout the deployment based on selector. Can someone please share how to achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by:

```bash
kubectl rollout status deployment --selector="key=value"
```

But this argument is added in kubctl [v1.24](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/99758), so if you have a lower version, you need to update it.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately we cannot update kubectl to v1.24